# Nativescript iOS 6.4.2 grid-layout throwing an error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.rows[measureSpec.getRowIndex()].children')

Tags: ios, angular, nativescript, grid-layout

While using Nativescript-angular we are getting the following error:

`File: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/layouts/grid-layout/grid-layout.ios.js:351:0: JS ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.rows[measureSpec.getRowIndex()].children')`

This is only on iOS 6.4.x and 6.5.x, on Android there is no issue. The client explodes with the following stack:

```
JavaScript stack trace:
file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/layouts/grid-layout/grid-layout.ios.js:351:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/layouts/grid-layout/grid-layout.ios.js:113:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/layouts/layout-base-common.js:136:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view-common.js:923:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/layouts/layout-base-common.js:134:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/layouts/layout-base-common.js:125:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/layouts/layout-base-common.js:133:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/layouts/grid-layout/grid-layout.ios.js:107:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view.ios.js:58:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view-helper/view-helper-common.js:26:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view-common.js:893:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/content-view/content-view.js:74:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view.ios.js:58:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view-helper/view-helper-common.js:26:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view-common.js:893:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/layouts/stack-layout/stack-layout.ios.js:52:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/layouts/layout-base-common.js:136:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view-common.js:923:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/layouts/layout-base-common.js:134:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/layouts/layout-base-common.js:125:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/layouts/layout-base-common.js:133:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/layouts/stack-layout/stack-layout.ios.js:50:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view.ios.js:58:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view-helper/view-helper-common.js:26:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view-common.js:893:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/layouts/stack-layout/stack-layout.ios.js:52:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/layouts/layout-base-common.js:136:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view-common.js:923:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/layouts/layout-base-common.js:134:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/layouts/layout-base-common.js:125:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/layouts/layout-base-common.js:133:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/layouts/stack-layout/stack-layout.ios.js:50:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view.ios.js:58:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view-helper/view-helper-common.js:26:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view-common.js:893:0
at file: node_modules/nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/ui-sidedrawer.ios.js:270:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view.ios.js:58:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view-helper/view-helper-common.js:26:0
at layoutView(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view-helper/view-helper.ios.js:64:0)
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view-helper/view-helper.ios.js:217:0
at UIApplicationMain([native code])
at run(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/application/application.ios.js:312:0)
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/angular/platform-common.js:210:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/angular/platform-common.js:111:0
at file: node_modules/@nativescript/angular/platform-common.js:91:0
at file:///app/bundle.js:9245:144
at ./main.tns.ts(file:///app/bundle.js:9250:34)
```

Has anyone seen something like this? Is there a way to solve the problem? not mask it out with:
`"discardUncaughtJsExceptions": true`

Any input or ideas welcome.

Comment: Ping me if you have a sample project that reproduces the issue so I could investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

We traced the cause of the fault to an `<Image>` on the grid that was setting the **row** value to *undefined*.

```
<GridLayout>
   <Image [row]="undefined" ....></Image>
</GridLayout>
```

Although this was a bug on our code, the interesting thing is that on Android this cause no problem and was interpreted as row="0" while on iOS this cause an exception.

It would be good if the behaviour were the same on both platforms.